# Tag delete suggestion: minecraft-thermos

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

There was apparently a tag [minecraft-thermos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-thermos) created for [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/331378/how-to-use-console-commands-and-see-console-output-on-minecraft-thermos-server-f), but there's just a single question with that tag, [no other question even contains the word "thermos"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=thermos) and most importantly:
Thermos is a modded Minecraft server and there are [only 13 questions tagged both](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods+minecraft-server) [minecraft-server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-server) and [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods), so it's unlikely that there will be many more questions for that software.

Therefore I suggest deleting the tag.

Comment: Honestly, judging from my experience at other SEs, the fact that the tag is only used for one question does not make it automatically eligible for deletion.

Comment: If it had a chance to be used again in the future, sure, but it would only be useful for a certain type of modded servers, which there are only 13 of in the past.

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, it could be used for another question about Thermos server, which I personally use, for example. Many Thermos-related problems are common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the tag from that question. Tags applied to no questions are automatically cleaned up.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks!